# Reusing the same host-visible buffer on different queue families

Tags: graphics, gpu, render, vulkan

Considering host-visible buffers (mostly related to streaming buffers, i.e. buffers backed by `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT` memory), let's imagine the following usage pattern:

1. Write new data to the mapped address on the host (after the proper synchronization).
2. Read the buffer with contents written in step 1 on queue family A.
3. Write new data to the mapped address on the host (after the proper synchronization).
4. Read the buffer with contents written in step 3 on queue family B.

Now, if I omit the queue family ownership transfer (QFOT), is the data written in step 3 inaccessible to queue family B in step 4?

The data written on the host becomes visible to the device when I submit the command(s) of step 4 using `vkQueueSubmit`, due to the implicit memory dependency of the [host write ordering guarantee](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap7.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes).

How does it play with different queue families?

Comment: Feels like less brutal version of [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs#1050](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1050) case 3. Anyway, reasonably well-researched inclarities should be commented against [the spec](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues), to make sure everyone is on the same page and possibly enforced by CTS.

Comment: @krOoze Anyway, a working solution could be (even QFOT is required or not) acquiring the ownership of the resource on queue family B without a QFOT (using the buffer on queue family B, probably with a dummy barrier affecting the proper subresource range) in a separate submission, just between step 2 and 3. Then writing new data on the host in step 3, finally submitting step 4. Do you think that a no-wait dummy resource barrier would be enough to "steal" the ownership?

Comment: Probably, but some driver maker could have a different opinion. Just ask Khronos and get it resolved. All I can be sure of is that a write does the trick (even so even that case is not all that well worded in the spec). That host writes are routed to the next first use queue seems relatively reasonable; hopefully you could even get resolved it that way by the spec makers. (It is how at least `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED` works btw).

Comment: @krOoze Will get it resolved by Khronos, just for the sake of curiosity. Actually using `VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT` for buffers could be a better solution to this, since someone told me that concurrent mode (unlike for images) does nothing for buffers, at least on known open source implementations, so that would be more performant than the additional semaphore wait requirement of my proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so we have a CPU modifiable buffer. And for some reason, this buffer was created in exclusive mode. And you want to do the following:

1. Write data to the buffer.
2. Copy the data using queue family A.
3. Write data to the buffer.
4. Copy the data using queue family B.

In order for step 4 to work, you are *required* to do an ownership transfer. The standard spells this out right before what you quoted:

> If memory dependencies are correctly expressed between uses of such a resource between two queues in different families, but no ownership transfer is defined, the contents of that resource are undefined for any read accesses performed by the second queue family.

You do have dependencies correctly expressed (I assume). But copying data is a "read access". And it is being performed by queue family B, which is different from queue family A. Therefore, step 4 (a "read access") triggers this clause: "the contents of that resource are undefined".

"Contents" means *all* of the contents. The ones you wrote in step 1 *and* step 3. All of them are undefined for step 4, unless you do a queue family ownership transfer.

Comment: Well, this is not good news for me. Wanted to avoid subresource QFOTs of the huge streaming buffers. Also, don't want to split the AMD available 256 MB of streaming memory between different queue types to provide a dedicated huge streaming buffer for each suitable queue family just to avoid QFOT, but still performance-wise that is the best solution if you want to use streaming both on dedicated graphics and compute queue families.

Comment: I think submitting a dummy or no-op buffer memory barrier on the new queue family is enough to steal the ownership from the previous queue family, since you start using the buffer on a new queue family, which triggers ownership migration (of course the previous contents become undefined, but who cares). Then the host can write new data to the mapped address, then in an another submission it can be read on the new queue family without any problem. This way you don't have to pay the cost of QFOT.

Comment: @plasmacel: "*Also, don't want to split the AMD available 256 MB of streaming memory between different queue types*" You shouldn't be using that as source data for *copies*. You should write to it on the CPU and use it *directly* by some GPU operation. That's why it's marked "device local". If you can't use that memory for some particular GPU operation, then you should just do a DMA from other storage. That 256MB is for CPU streaming of data you want to use, not copy.

Comment: You can avoid any ownership transfer costs by avoiding using the same streaming buffers for different queues. Or just not using the exclusive flag on those buffers. If you need to stage for multiple queue families, I don't know why you would bother with an exclusive buffer.

Comment: That is an another scenario, for streaming buffers, not staging buffers. Their usage is different (indirect vs direct), but the problem of queue family ownership transfer and host writes are the same. The case of staging buffers is only better because their practical usage allows to use them only on a single queue family, which is selected for transfers (and based on the selection, may or may not unified with the graphics/compute queue). I don't mix the concepts of staging and streaming buffers/memory. Still, the theoretical problem is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237796/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-plasmacel).